# JUnit UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.util.Log.isLoggable(Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, android, junit, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm getting the following error when I run a JUnit test on an android app that uses apachehttp-client. The app runs successfully on my test device and on an emulator. A login JUnit test also passes but the rest of the JUnit tests fail whenever the app tries to use the apachehttp-client to read data from a server.

The test seems to fail at httpClient.execute

```
try {
        URL businessPartnersResource = new URL(
                session.getServer().getUrl(), "BusinessPartners");

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(businessPartnersResource.toURI());
        session.attachToRequest(request);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory.getClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        switch (status) {
        case HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK: {
```

Here's the Failure Trace

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.util.Log.isLoggable(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
at android.util.Log.isLoggable(Native Method)
at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestClientConnControl.process(RequestClientConnControl.java:76)
at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:251)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:168)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:458)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frustrating, but you'll have to use a [RobolectricTestRunner](http://robolectric.org/) instead of the standard JUnit one.

isLoggable is a native method so its not available at runtime.

If you use Volley or the apachehttp-client, the biggest issue is that isLoggable is called as a field instantiation, for example:

`private static final DEBUG = Log.isLoggable(..);`

Which completely messes things up given that this method is simply not available at all within those *libraries* at runtime, so even an `AndroidTestCase` can't save you.

Luckily, Robolectric handles it perfectly.

**Edit April 4, 2017**

JUnit 5 is available now and I have not tested with this testrunner.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, try extending AndroidTestCase in your test class. The error is due to classes that can be found only on the android runtime (Device\Emulator)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it happened when running a specific test on [`kotest`](https://github.com/kotest/kotest). I had to run all the tests at once instead of one by one.

Answer (score -3):

Running the JUnit tests on Android Projects.

The only difference while running junit test in android is that you’ll be calling Run As > Android JUnit Test instead of just JUnit Test like you are used to in java.

That’s all! Hope you like it!